# Are generators time efficent?

Tags: python, generator, data-generation

I understand that generators in python atleast are memeory efficent as it deals with one item at a time but how does this make it time efficent (if it is) ?

Specifically, say I'm using generator function to load one data at a time for a machine learning task. At the end of the day, I will still need to loop over all the data elements and load them one at a time( using generator function). Yes, this is memeory efficent but this should instead take a lot more time to load the entire dataset than say loading all at once. Is my intuition right ?

```
#sample_code

def my_gen():
    for i in range(1000):
    features = np.random.randn(32,32,3)
    labels = np.random.randint(0,1, size = 1)
    yield features, labels
```

Comment: What makes you think that generators are time efficient? Can whatever hypothetical backend you are loading a dataset from actually load the entire dataset at once?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not sure if generators are time efficent and that's exactlymy question. Regarding the second half of the comment, say I have a csv file storing image data(pixels). I usually use pandas dataframe to load the entire data at once and then perform some preprocessing on the  entire dataframe ( basically vectorization). The issue with the above method is that I have to load the entire dataset into my memeory first which is not efficient if my dataset is say of 100gb.

Comment: continuing the previous comment..

So the next alternative that I couldof think of is generators as it solves the problem of memeory efficiency but here im looping over indivudial elements and hence I'm afarid I might lose the advantages of vectoized implementation ( only if generators are indeed not time efficeint which I'm not sure).

Comment: looks like machine learning because of: "features, labels" If you have 100GB You might consider Dimensionality reduction or make a smaller sample dataset. Generators are mostly not faster just more memory efficient.

Comment: @Andreas the issue is it's very common to have 100GB ( for instance, speech data, video data) of data even after doing PCA and other dimensionality reduction. Moreover to do PCA i'll have to load the data first right ? so I will again run into same issue of having limited memeory. Also, the purpose of using generators is to create batches of data and then train my model on each indivudial batches but again, with this approach my system will be less time effcieient because like you said generators are not time efficent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating a generator as a lazy sequence, it is usually *less* time efficient as a corresponding eager sequence.

```py
%timeit sum((x*2 for x in range(5000)))  # lazy generator
366 µs ± 9.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit sum([x*2 for x in range(5000)])  # eager list
308 µs ± 3.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

This is because the generator holds intermediate state, which must be resumed for each item. In contrast, eagerly creating a sequence has to handle the intermediate state just once.

Keep in mind however that the overhead of generators is basically fixed. If each item takes a long time to compute, the constant overhead of the generator becomes negligible. When items are processed one-at-a-time, s also allow to free processed items, reducing the overall load on the process – possibly reaching a net time advantage at some point.

---

The advantage of generators is that lazyness allows to represent *infinite* sequences and *latency*  – a generator is "n times O(i)" compared to a sequence "plain O(ni)". This allows a generator to produce *each* item at reliable time efficiency, even if the entire process would be delayed infinitely.

An infinite, *eager* sequence would have infinite time complexity but an infinite, *lazy* generator only produces items as needed.

```py
def randoms():
    """Infinite stream of random numbers"""
    while True:
        yield random.random()
```

Likewise, generators allow *external data sources* time between providing each item. This can make a generator more efficient when the data source has notable latency between providing items.

Answer (score 1):

No. Generators are, inherently, slower than similar alternatives (like list comprehensions).

**But**

If you're looking to reduce memory by loading data with generators, you probably shouldn't worry about this performance difference. It's more often the case that the performance bottleneck be at disk I/O and/or syscalls. The penalty by employing generators plays a negligible role in overall performance.

So the final answer is: Go ahead with generators. Its performance should be the last thing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are a feature you use. the implementation for a specific task is and whether it scales or not is a different story.
You can read a single item each time, and you can read a bulk of data each time and process them at each time.
So depending on your situation, the later can be a much better option. in which case, it will be more time efficient as well.